# GNU Fortran ctime equivalent in IBM xl fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to build a Fortran codebase on an IBM xl system with one source file giving compilation error as follows:

```
line 152.16: 1516-036 (S) Entity ctime has undefined type
```

After some Googling, I figure that `ctime` is a GNU Fortran function which is why the xl compilers are not liking it. Can someone suggest if there is any alternative function for ctime in IBM xl fortran compilers.

The `ctime` function converts a system time value to string. Ref section 9.74 pp. 124 of https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran.pdf

Comment: I'm far too lazy to look at the gfortran documentation to find out what `ctime` does.  Why don't you tell us ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Thanks, made an edit to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Fortran, since the 1990 standard if I remember correctly, defines a standard subroutine called `date_and_time` which will return the current date and time (if the computer it is running on is capable of telling a program that) in character and in numeric forms.  Consult your favourite documentation set for details.

If your problem is to convert a date and time value stored in some numeric format to a string, that's what *internal writes* are for.  If you don't know how to use internal writes to transform numbers into strings then (a) tut, and (b) ask for clarification.

If your entire codebase is infected with `ctime` you could write your own implementation and have the IBM compiler compile it for you.

Comment: I find that IBM compiler has an equivalent function with an underscore appended to it: `ctime_` replacing this does not work. I am not well versed with Fortran, any suggestions how I can use it? Also wondering if there are any flags that you are aware of that help with intercompiler compatibilities? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: So do a global search and replace on your code base to change every occurrence of `ctime` to `ctime_`.  Make sure you've got it all under version control so you can rebuild the gfortran version without another global search and replace.  As for intercompiler compatibilities, nope, no advice on that front.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent subroutine is `ctime_`, as mentioned in one of the answers, but note that the order of the arguments is different.

gfortran:

```
call ctime(time, result)
where time is an intent(in) integer argument
and result is an intent(out) character argument
```

XL Fortran:

```
call ctime_(str, time)
where str is the intent(out) character argument
and time is the intent(in) integer argument
```

You can find the full documentation of `ctime_` in the XL Fortran language reference in the service and utility procedures chapter.  [Here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAT4T_15.1.0/com.ibm.xlf151.linux.doc/language_ref/sup-ctime.html) is a link to the function in the XL Fortran 15.1 language reference: